# How to programmatically run the GlueGen emitter in Java?

Tags: java

The guide on [gluegen](https://jogamp.org/gluegen/doc/manual/#SecAnt) only has a section on how to run it using Apache Ant. Is it possible to programmatically run the JNI generation process?

Comment: Answered here: http://forum.jogamp.org/how-to-programmatically-run-the-gluegen-emitter-in-java-tp4039177p4039178.html

Comment: @gouessej. ah thanks. I just saw this. if you put it down an answer here, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: As you wish but you could investigate a bit more and answer your own question by adding some additional information so that the next person having the same problem could benefit of your knowledge :)

Comment: i never thought of it like that. thanks =)